# results of one of the ways to declare a new object with a parent class and a subclass

Tags: java

I have a Java-related question.

I have a public class Parent and its subclass public class Child extends Parent.

If I were to declare a new object as

```
Parent p = new Child();
```

would `p` be able to use the methods of Child and Parent? Or only Parent?

Additionally, what would be the difference in declaring `p` as

```
Child p = new Child();
```

if Child extends parent already?

Comment: I think you need to read more on Inheritance in java, Please have look on this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: I don't want to spoil your fun by telling you the answer. All you need to do is write some methods for both `Parent` and `Child` and see which ones you can invoke on `p`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

Think of it like a TV remote and a particular brand of TV.

The parent class is the older Samsung model. The child class is the newer Samsung model (and can do more things!).

If you do `Parent p = new Child();` You're saying that you want to use the remote control for the older Samsung model on the new Samsung model. You're allowed to do this of course, but you won't have all the buttons to use all the new features of the `Child` class. Declared like this, `p` can access only `Parent` methods.

However, if you do `Child p = new Child();`, then you've bought a brand new remote to go with your new tv - now you can use ALL the features of your tv. `p` can now access both `Parent` and `Child` methods.

Comment: Thank you, this analogy cleared up a lot. I asked my teacher, but it is much easier for me to visualize the answer with text descriptions.

Comment: @Mattik No problem - That's what we're here for.. kind of.

Answer (score 0):

**Java Inheritance**

```
class Parent
{
    public void p1()
    {
        System.out.println("Parent method");
    }
}
public class Child extends Parent {
    public void c1()
    {
        System.out.println("Child method");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Child cobj = new Child();
        cobj.c1();   //method of Child class
        cobj.p1();   //method of Parent class 
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Child method
Parent method
```

Comment: what you have mentioned is right. But the question he mentioned is realted to  reference conversion.. sub class object to super class reference...